# How websites do payment for cinema ticket, hotel rooms

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have a question regarding payment.

I know how to do payment using paypal, payu or google checkout or credit card etc. But here are example websites doing payment :

I am from INDIA and here is website :

link : http://www.bookmyshow.com

After all too many cinemas in country and how they know about seats available and when do payment book the ticket.

link : http://www.airbnb.com

Above website known for hotel they do same thing. Person select hotel and select room then payment. Do they give check to hotel or what ? as there are too many hotel.

I am little confused about payments for booking ticket, hotel room etc.

Thanks if anyone have information regarding this.

Comment: Mandeep, I'm a little confused on what your question actually is. Are you asking how Airbnb distribute's their payments to their sub-merchants (people who own the rooms)?

Comment: Yes exactly, Sorry for i can't tell what i wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Airbnb uses the Braintree Marketplace API: https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/marketplace

That enables you to to take payments and then split payments between you and your providers.

Unfortunately though the Marketplace API is not available in India. You'll need to find an equivalent provider in India.

Comment: Thanks, i will find service in india.